# Is there a similar function to getHistoryForKey in Hyperledger Fabricthat also provides transaction details?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am able to retrieve the transaction history of a particular key in Hyperledger Fabric using getHistoryForKey.  However, the information it provides is limited to the transaction ID, timestamp, etc.

I need a similar function that provides a history but gives details such as the name of the function and parameters of a particular transaction.

Does such function exist in Hyperledger Fabric?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You could use an attribute to indicate/store the transaction name/params invoked (and it gets stored), using `getFunctionAndParameters()`.  From Fabric 1.4, do something like:

```
let ret = ctx.stub.getFunctionAndParameters();
let args = ret.params; // params array
let fcn = ret.fcn; // function/transaction called
```